# How to remove a Html elements inner html with knockout observable variable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How to clear an element's inner html with knockout js from javascript code side.

In js file:

```
var mustDestroy = ko.observable(false);

//some code later

mustDestroy(true);
```

In html:

```
<div data-bind="some binding here to clear inside of div with related to mustDestroy">
    <p>some html here</p>
    <a href="foo">foo</a>
    <img src="foo" />
</div>
```

Becomes (on the fly):

```
<div>
</div>
```

I need knockout related solution for this question. Not only javascript please.

Comment: Your quest is quite unclear... what do you mean on destroy? However you probably need the `with` binding: http://jsfiddle.net/tsvW4/

Comment: I mean clearing inside of html element on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you later change the knockout observable back? The if or ifnot binding works well for removing the contents of a div.

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: mustDestroy">
    <p>some html here</p>
    <a href="foo">foo</a>
    <img src="foo" />
</div>
```

The above solution works well if you want the div to be empty any time that your variable is true.

You could also write your own binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.destroyOnTrue = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
            ko.virtualElements.emptyNode(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should be able to use the html binding on your div as follows:

```
<div data-bind="html: MyHtml"></div>
```

Where My html contains a load of html in ko.observable() function.

More here

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html

An alternative would be to use the visibility binding to hide the element.

Beyond this a customBinding is probably your only option.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Here you can use the 
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            $(element).html("");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't want to put my html code inside javascript file. Do you know can I use it with template binding. Basically I want to do it over a javascript variable.

Comment: Added a few suggestions to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I actually do now is hiding. So the other answer and comment by @nemesv providing my needs.